If i know a battery's internal resistance, how accurately can I predict its maximum current?
Is my thinking on the right track?  Say I have a AA battery that the manufacturer claims has an internal resistance of 0.5 ohms.  Can I say that the maximum current ...
$$i=\frac{v}{R_I+R_L}=\frac{1.5}{0.5+R_L}$$
... will occur when the load resistance is zero, so the maximum current will be 3 amps?  Were I to short the battery, for instance, 3 amps is the greatest current that would flow?
This of course ignores the effect of heat and assumes that the internal resistance doesn't change as a result.  But am I at least considering the role of internal resistance correctly?

I like the typo in your title, "infernal resistance": Yes, the internal resistance of batteries is truly hellish! I'm still fixing the typo, but I thought I'd let you know that this simple thing brought me joy :)

@MarcusMüller I preferred it with the typo! Lol

No joy to us late comers now @MarcusMüller the spoiler LOL

This will give you the absolute max current, so allow you to size the wiring to not burn out if the battery gets shorted. Bear in mind the battery voltage will drop quickly when delivering this current due to polarisation, and will drop over the life of the battery, and the internal resistance will rise over the life of the battery, and nothing will stay stable with temperature, so it's not a predictable current.

Yes, that's more-or-less correct. It's the greatest current that could flow with just the battery and a resistor. Of course you could connect batteries in parallel (series won't increase the current since each battery has the same internal resistance) or force current through the battery from some external source (possibly causing an explosion if the current is high enough).
It would be perfectly correct if the open-circuit voltage was exactly 1.5V and if the internal resistance behaved like an accurate and stable resistor. In fact, none of that is true. The internal resistance will change with the charge state, the recent history of the battery, and with temperature (including self-heating).
In particular, the internal resistance of batteries increases as they discharge,- a more profound effect than open-ciruit voltage change, so checking battery voltage under load is a more reliable indicator of state-of-charge than looking at open-circuit voltage.
If I test a random fresh Kirkland brand AA alkaline cell into (almost) a short circuit I get about 2A briefly, and the open-circuit voltage is 1.62V. Some types of batteries can produce enough current and internal dissipation to damage themselves (and others via fire or explosion) so this test is not recommended in general.
